# RowUpdating Not working showing me input string is not in correct format

Tags: c#, gridview

protected void gv_card_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

```
    int result = 0;
    CreditCard prod = new CreditCard();
    GridViewRow row = gv_card.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    string id = gv_card.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    string  tid = ((TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;
    string  tnumber = ((TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
    string  texpirydate = ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
    string tcvv = ((TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
    string tcardtype = ((TextBox)row.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;
    string tholdername = ((TextBox)row.Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text;

    result = prod.CardUpdate(int.Parse(tid), tholdername, tnumber,texpirydate,  int.Parse(tcvv), tcardtype );
    if (result > 0)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Product updated successfully');</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Product NOT updated');</script>");
    }
    gv_card.EditIndex = -1;
    bind();
}
```

}

Above is my Code but it just cant seem to update my gridview

Comment: I'm going to guess the value of `tid` or `tcvv` fail to parse to `int` because of null or non-numeric values. This should be pretty simple to debug if you step through and read the documentation of `Parse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message is likely coming from your call to `int.Parse(string)`, which expects the string to be a valid integer. To handle this, you can instead use `int.TryParse(string, out int)`, which will return true or false if it is able to parse the string. If it's successful, the `out` parameter will contain the parsed integer value.

So you would first try to parse the integer fields. If that fails you could return an error message, and if it succeeds then you can use the integers directly in your call to `CardUpdate`:

```
int tidValue;
int tcvvValue;

if (!int.TryParse(tid, out tidValue))
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('The value specified for TID is not an integer.');</script>");
}
else if (!int.TryParse(tcvv, out tcvvValue))
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('The value specified for TCVV is not an integer.');</script>");
}
else
{
    result = prod.CardUpdate(tidValue, tholdername, tnumber, texpirydate, tcvvValue, tcardtype);

    if (result > 0)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Product updated successfully');</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Product NOT updated');</script>");
    }
}
```